# Elevator system schematic diagram in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am working on a project related to elevator group control systems, and I am writing a paper right now, but I need to show a diagram that depicts an elevator system diagram in the paper, the example is shown below.

Could someone please tell me from where to start in order to obtain the shown results? I already have experience in using Tikz library and PGFPlots, but I only used them to create simple plots.

[image: Elevator system schematic diagram]

Edit: this is the code I have tried, but the results are far from what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid]{1}{5}
\gantttitle{Title}{5} \\
\ganttbar{}{1}{1} \\
\ganttbar{}{2}{2} \\
\ganttbar{}{3}{3} \\
\ganttbar{}{4}{4} \\
\ganttbar{}{5}{5} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JouleV I tried building it with a package called pgfgantt, that creates gantt diagrams, but it was not exactly what I wanted, as Gantt diagrams are horizontal, and I want the diagram to be vertical, as elevators move vertically.

Comment: Add your code to the question. Any codes are helpful for us to help you.

Comment: @JouleV I just did, thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{elevator/.style={fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=0.7cm,minimum width=0.2cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,>=latex]
\foreach \i/\elev/\mione/\mitwo in {
    1/7/8/9,
    4/1/3/6
} {
    \draw (\i,0) -- (\i,9);
    \foreach \j in {0,...,9} \draw (\i-.1,\j) -- (\i+.1,\j);
    \node at (\i,10) {Shaft \i};
    \path (\i-.1,\elev) node[left=.3333em,elevator] {};
    \path (\i-.1,\mione) node[left] {$-$};
    \path (\i-.1,\mitwo) node[left] {$-$};
}
\foreach \i/\elev/\mione/\mitwo in {2/6/0/4,3/8/0/0} {
    \draw (\i,0) -- (\i,9);
    \foreach \j in {0,...,9} \draw (\i-.1,\j) -- (\i+.1,\j);
    \node at (\i,10) {Shaft \i};
    \path (\i+.1,\elev) node[right=.3333em,elevator] {};
    \path (\i+.1,\mione) node[right] {$-$};
    \path (\i+.1,\mitwo) node[right] {$-$};
}
\draw (5,0) -- (5,9);
\foreach \i in {0,...,9} \draw (4.9,\i) -- (5.1,\i);
\node at (5,10) {Buttons};
\foreach \i in {2,3} \path (5.1,\i) node[right] {$+$};
\foreach \i in {5,8} \path (4.9,\i) node[left] {$+$};
\path (4.9,0) node[left] (up) {up};
\path (5.1,9) node[right] (dn) {dn};
\draw[->] (up) -- ++ (0,2);
\draw[->] (dn) -- ++ (0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]